# a word for becoming emotionally involved

Tags: single-word-requests

a word for when someone becomes emotionally involved with what's happening.
It's a word close to empathy, for example, when someone is telling a really touching story and it's like you're feeling what's like under their skin.

It doesn't mean to be sorry, but when something someone says/does etc. gets and holds onto you, and you feel attached to it

Comment: Gripping? Invested?

Comment: It connects with you.

Comment: How would you use the word? Please [edit] to include a sample sentence.

Comment: Kindly supply a sample sentence(s), as required for 'single word requests'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one of the definitions of "smitten".  You can be smitten emotionally with any emotion - emotionally smitten.

> "What a story she told! I was truly smitten with all of the emotions she brought out."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/smitten